# How do I make the 'Listed Price' show the default value?

Tags: orocommerce

I'm new to OroCommerce, and I'm a bit stuck with product pricing.

In our environment, we're manually setting the product's price against their corresponding price list, instead of auto-calculating them. They appear for the user when they use an account with the price list assigned to them. However, the "Your Price" and "Listed Price" are both the same, but we want the "Listed Price" to show the default price value.

How do I make the "Listed Price" show the default value of the product? Do I have to automatically calculate the price at listing level?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, "Your Price" shows the price for the selected quantity and unit.
If you want to show there the default price, you have to customize it. There are a few options:

1. You can create a separate price list with default prices and display prices directly from the price list in a storefront, without price calculation.
2. Also, you can [create a new price attribute](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/price-attributes/) with the default price and render the value from it.